# Seting Pixmap on QLabel as a response to currentIndexChanged event on QComboBox causes program to crash

Tags: qt, opencv

So I want to set a new image on my label when I change item on my ComboBox. Here's slot function:

```
void MainWindow::comboBox1Changed(int index)
{
    ui->cameraImage->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(maskPicture));
}
```

maskPicture is a image converted from Mat format (OpenCV) using this funcion:

```
maskPicture = QImage((uchar*) img.data, img.cols, img.rows, img.step, QImage::Format_RGB888);
```

The problem is that program crashes, but it doesn't crash always. Sometimes it changes picture properly. Also there is another function updating picture the same way that is ran when timer event occurs but it always works fine. The problem is only with comboBox. I can change item in comboBox few times to change the picture but eventually program crashes

Comment: You need to tell us where and how it crashes.

Comment: It crashes in slot function while exectuing this function:
ui->cameraImage->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(maskPicture));

Comment: How does it crash though? What's the error message you get? Is `ui` a valid pointer? `cameraImage`?

Answer (score 0):

I did some changes and now it kind of works. Variable maskPicture is now Mat type instead of QImage and I do convertion in slot function. Still no idea why it was crashing before but at least it works now.